# How to publish contents only of a specific folder?

Tags: npm

How to streamline `npm release` when I want to include only specific path(s)?

I have `./src` and `./dist` files in my repository. I want to effectively publish only the contents of `./dist` + `./package.json`.

Using `.npmignore` to ignore `./src` will simply ignore the `./src` folder. I want to include only the contents of `./dist`, i.e. now user would need to do `require('my-package/dist/something')`. I want to make it `require('my-package/something')`. `./something` is contained in `./dist`.

Comment: I am having this exact issue. With the main: "dist/" I can make the entry point work seamlessly, but if anyone wants to include something lower , they need the /dist/ in the path and I don't want that.

Answer (score 13):

The way I have done it at the moment is, I have created a bash script:

```bash
npm run build
cp package.json ./dist
# or, if you need to have package.json "main" entry different,
# e.g. for being able to use `npm link`, you need to replace "main" value:
# sed 's#"main": "./dist/index.js"#"main": "./index.js"#' package.json > ./dist/package.json
cd ./dist
npm publish
```

Answer (score 0):

For cross-platform compatibilty use [shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx):

```
npm run build
shx cp package.json ./dist
shx cd ./dist
npm publish
```