# npm publish a package with only the children of dist folder

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-publish

My package is structured as follows:

```
mypackage
   |--- src
   |     |--- component1
   |     `--- component2
   `--- dist
         |--- component1
         `--- component2
```

When I publish it to npm, I would like it to look like the following, without the `dist` directory:

```
mypackage
   |--- component1
   `--- component2
```

The idea is that when I import from this package, the imports should look file this:

```
import component1 from 'mypackage/component1'
```

an not this (notice the extra `dist`):

```
import component1 from 'mypackage/dist/component1'
```

How to achieve this? I currently have a files section in my package.json which publishes with the extra `dist` and I don't want that:

```
"files": [
  "dist/"
]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on the answer from [How to publish contents only of a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862712/how-to-publish-contents-only-of-a-specific-folder) this may be of use:

```
npm run build
cp package.json ./dist
# or, if you need to have package.json "main" entry different,
# e.g. for being able to use `npm link`, you need to replace "main" 
value:
# sed 's#"main": "./dist/index.js"#"main": "./index.js"#' package.json > ./dist/package.json
cd ./dist
npm publish
```

So just basically copy your package.json into the `dist/` folder and then run `npm publish` from within the `dist/` folder

Comment: Thank you!
This should be documented on npm's docs

Comment: This did not work for me, though programmatically changing the outDir entry in my `tsconfig.json` from `./dist/` to `./` did the trick!